# Use Different Plugin On Different View (Mobile,Computer View)

Tags: wordpress

I have an css issue about one plugin on responsive view and I want to hide on mobile. I want to use another plugin only for mobile view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query for hiding element on desktop and mobile

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 200px)  {

    .container_mobikle{
display:block !important;
    }
}
```